# Counting and summing values of records, filtered by a dictionary of foreign keys in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having trouble with a Django query for this simplified model:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField

class Task(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(
                               'Client',
                               )
    task_type = models.ForeginKey(
                                  'Task_Type',
                                  )

class Task_Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField

class Task_Value(models.Model):
    value_num = models.DecimalField
    task = models.ForeignKey(
                             'Task',
                              )
```

I have a list of foreign keys created by a method of Client. I want to do two things, first I want to count all the tasks that have a task_type by the name of "XYZ", limited to clients in the dictionary.  Secondly I want to sum all the value_num for all the tasks by the name of "ABC", limited to Clients in the dictionary.  These two values will be summed and divided by the number of clients in the dictionary

Below is the method I am have (and is working) for a single client, but I am having trouble with iterating this over the list.

```
cnt = Task.objects.filter(client=self.pk,event_type__name__exact="XYZ").count()
tasks = Task.objects.filter(client=self.pk,event_type__name__exact="ABC")[0]
value = tasks.task_value_set.get(field__name__exact='ABC').value_num
answer = int(cnt+value)
```

**EDIT:**
The list is derived from this:

```
group = Client.objects.filter(pk__in=client_list)
```

where the method generates the client list.

Comment: What's the format of the dictionary?

Comment: It looks like this: [<Client: user_name>,<Client: user_name>,<Client: user_name>]

Comment: Er, that's a list (or a queryset), not a dictionary.

Comment: Your right, sorry I'm a bit new to Django.  I corrected the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Count all tasks that have `task_type` by the name of "XYZ", limited to clients in queryset**

```
Task.objects.filter(client__in=clients, task_type__name='XYZ').count()
```

**Sum all the `value_num` for all the tasks by the name of "ABC", limited to clients in the queryset.**

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Task.objects.filter(client__in=clients, task_type__name='ABC').annotate(Sum('task_value__value_num'))
```